# How to show a list of processes from a group?

Tags: process

I want a simple command to list all the processes and its information from a given PGID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way to proactively tell `ps` to select based on pgrp, so you have to request that column then filter on it; something like:

```
ps axo pgrp,stat,euid,ruid,tty,tpgid,sess,ppid,pid,pcpu,comm | awk -v pgrp=3668 '$1 == pgrp'

ps -eo pgrp,pid,comm | sed -n -e 1p -e ' /3668/ p'

PGRP=3668; ps -eo pgrp,pid,comm | sed -n -e 1p -e " / $PGRP / p"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pgrep -ag PGID
```

If `PGID` is `0`, it means pgrep's own process group, eg.

```
$ cat | cat | cat | pgrep -ag0
7301 cat
7302 cat
7303 cat
```

(notice that `pgrep` never includes itself in the listing, and `pkill` never kills itself)

Answer (score 0):

On Darwin, `ps -g $pgid` does work as you ask.

On Linux, it doesn't work and you need to use some other solution. You can use `ps --ppid $ppid` which lists all child processes of the given parent.